# How to figure out the type if it is ambiguous type?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

I am a Haskell beginner and I am having some trouble understanding this. I have 2 functions defined in a file like this:

```hs
expr n x = (x ^ n)/(fact n)


fact n
  | n == 0 = 1
  | otherwise = n * fact (n - 1)
```

But when I try to run say `expr 3 2` , I keep getting an error like this:

```
*Main> expr 3 2

<interactive>:31:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 19 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I checked the types for the various expressions and I see this:

```
*Main> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
*Main> :t (^)
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
*Main> :t 3 ^ 6
3 ^ 6 :: Num a => a
*Main> :t fact
fact :: (Eq p, Num p) => p -> p
*Main> :t fact 3
fact 3 :: (Eq p, Num p) => p
*Main> :t 9 / 6
9 / 6 :: Fractional a => a
```

But I cannot figure out what types to give my functions to avoid this. I tried giving my fact function a type like this since (/) expects Fractional:

```
fact :: (Fractional a) => Int -> a
```

But if I try giving my function types, the file doesn't even load in ghci. I can post the error message I get from attempting to load my file with types if that helps.

If I try to add type to the show used when evaluating the expression, that doesn't work either:

```hs
*Main> expr 3 2 :: String

<interactive>:37:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional String) arising from a use of ‘expr’
    • In the expression: expr 3 2 :: String
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = expr 3 2 :: String

<interactive>:37:6: error:
    • No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal ‘3’
    • In the first argument of ‘expr’, namely ‘3’
      In the expression: expr 3 2 :: String
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = expr 3 2 :: String
*Main> expr 3 2 :: Integer

<interactive>:38:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of ‘expr’
    • In the expression: expr 3 2 :: Integer
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = expr 3 2 :: Integer
```

Comment: It's the implicit call to `show` made by `ghci` that doesn't know which instance of `Show` to use to convert the result to a `String`. Try `expr 3 2 :: Integer`, `expr 3 2 :: Float`, etc to pick one.

Comment: I tried it. That din work either. I'll edit my question to add the response from that. I tried, Integer, Double, Float.

Comment: You can't pick *any* return type, only those compatible with the constraints imposed by the operators you are using.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am trying to figure out. What should be the type here because I am not super familiar with how the types work out. The type returned by (/) is Fractional correct? So should I do `expr 3 2 :: Fractional a` or something like that?

Comment: In Haskell, arithmetic operators, except (^), force their two operands to be of the same type. So if you want Double values, you just have to force the denominator to be of  Double type, like this for example: `expr n x = (x ^ n) / ((fromIntegral (fact n))::Double)`  ; that will force type ambiguities out and so make the expression show'able.

Comment: Haskell is inferring the correct type for you: `:t expr` will return `(Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a -> a`, because the use of `/` requires the arguments to have a `Fractional` instance, and the use of `^` forces an `Integral` instance. If you want to call `show` on it (as `ghci` tries to do), `a` must have a `Show` instance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, operator `/`, just like for + - *, forces its two operands to have the same type (and that's also the type of the result). Operator `^` is an exception, and its result has to have the same type as its left operand. Note that for floating-point types, you also have the `**` exponentiation operator à la Fortran.

Rules are explained in more detail in this [tutorial](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html).

Unfortunately that means that mixed-mode arithmetics is somewhat less easy to get in Haskell than in some well-known imperative languages. If need be, conversion function [fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=fromIntegral&scope=set%3Astackage) can be used. It gives the compiler license to insert some appropriate conversion.

For the present situation, if a broad type signature is desired, it can be achieved for example like this:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  ExplicitForAll       #-}

fact :: Integral nt => nt -> nt
fact n = if (n <= 0)  then  1  else  n * fact (n - 1)

expr :: forall nt ft.  (Integral nt, Fractional ft) => nt -> ft -> ft 
expr n x = (x ^ n) / ((fromIntegral (fact n)) :: ft)
```

**Testing under `ghci`:**

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :load q65254539.hs
...
Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> expr 2 3
 4.5
 λ> expr 2 pi
 4.934802200544679
 λ> 
 λ> expr 3 (4::Double)
 10.666666666666666
 λ>
```

Comment: This does work! Thank you so much for the explanation. I kinda get it now but I am going to do some more reading. I had never used `fromIntegral` before.